# Javascript C# Unicode Strings - headscratcher

Tags: c#, javascript, string, unicode, encoding

If I convert a Bytearray in Javascript to a string using the following method:

```
convertByteArrayToString: function(byteArray)
{
    var s = '';
    for(var i = 0;i < byteArray.length;i++)
            {
                    s += String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i])
            }
    return s;
},
```

How do I then convert this string back to a byte array in C#?

I have tried all three of the following:

```
 System.Text.UnicodeEncoding encoding = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(myString);
 System.Text.UTF32Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF32Encoding().GetBytes(myString);
 System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(myString);
```

The closest is the first one, but it returns a Byte array which is double the length of the original with every other element in the array being 0 and sometimes an incorrect value or two.

As far as I am aware, the String.fromCharCode works in Unicode, so how do get this to interoperate with C#?

This is driving me nuts!

Edit:

Here is an example,

Original Byte array:
[139, 104, 166, 35, 8, 42, 216, 160, 235, 153, 23, 143, 105, 3, 24, 255]

My function converts this to:
"h¦#*Ø ëiÿ"

In C#, attempting to decode this String to a byte array yields the following results:

Using System.Text.UnicodeEncoding gives:
[142,0,139,0,104,0,166,0,35,0,8,0,42,0,216,0,32,0,235,0,153,0,23,0,143,0,105,0,30,24,0,255,0]

Comment: It's not "twice the length". Strings in C# are little-endian UTF16, so a string of 30 `chars` is 60 bytes long. Most common alphanumeric chars are below 0xFF so the second (MORE significant) byte is 0.

Comment: Retagged, encoding is not encryption. Unicode character points can be character-encoded, e.g. using UTF-8 or UTF-16. Encoding is the method of encoding data (bytes are normally implied), e.g. Base-64 or hexadecimals. Encryption is a method of creating confidentiality, e.g. AES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) has  `Crypto.charenc.UTF8.stringToBytes()` and `Crypto.charenc.UTF8.bytesToString()`, that werk perfectly with UTF-8 encoding in C#.

**Edit**

After discussion it turns out, the OP wants to transport a `byte[]` from JS into C# - this is better done via `base64` encoding (I recomend the same JS toolkit)

Comment: Which means your byte array is not a valid UTF8 String. Maybe the question should be asked differently: Do you want to transport a `byte[]` from JS into C# ?  If this is so, don't go via strings, go via base64 (crypto-js also), we do this all the time for encrypted passwords, so I guess it works ;-)

Comment: "don't go via strings, go via base64 (crypto-js also)" - worked a treat, thank you